# Why is the echo ping not reaching the destination?

Tags: networking, icmp, raw-sockets

I'm trying to implement an ICMP echo ping packet myself using Raw Socket. When taking tcpdump on my Linux machine, I'm finding that the Echo ping request has been successfully sent but when I'm observing the incoming packets in my Windows machine using Wireshark, no incoming ICMP requests are observed.

I've written the following code to implement the ICMP echo request and reply.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h> 
#include <time.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <signal.h> 
#include <time.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h> 
#include <netpacket/packet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>


#define PING_PKT_S 64 
#define PORT_NO 0 
#define PING_SLEEP_RATE 1000000 
#define RECV_TIMEOUT 1 

int pingloop=1; 

struct ping_pkt 
{
   struct ethhdr eth; 
   struct ip ip;    
   struct icmphdr hdr; 
   char msg[PING_PKT_S-sizeof(struct icmphdr)]; 
}g_pckt; 


typedef struct ping_ctx{
   int tos;
   int ttl;
   char srcIP[200];
   char dstIP[200];
   int r_sock;
}ping_ctx;

unsigned short checksum(void *b, int len)  
{
 unsigned short *buf = b; 
 unsigned int sum=0; 
 unsigned short result; 

 for ( sum = 0; len > 1; len -= 2 ) 
     sum += *buf++; 
 if ( len == 1 ) 
     sum += *(unsigned char*)buf; 
 sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF); 
 sum += (sum >> 16); 
 result = ~sum; 
 return result; 
} 

void intHandler(int dummy) 
{ 
pingloop=0; 
}  

void fill_ip_h(struct ip *ip, ping_ctx* ctx)
{
    ip->ip_src.s_addr = inet_addr(ctx->srcIP);
    ip->ip_dst.s_addr = inet_addr(ctx->dstIP);
    ip->ip_v = 4;
    ip->ip_hl = sizeof*ip >> 2;
    ip->ip_tos = (unsigned char)(ctx->tos);
    ip->ip_len = htons(sizeof(g_pckt)-sizeof(struct ethhdr));
    ip->ip_id = htons(4321);
    ip->ip_off = htons(0);
    ip->ip_ttl = (unsigned char)(ctx->ttl);
    ip->ip_p = 1;
    ip->ip_sum = 0; /* Let kernel fills in */
 }

 void fill_icmp_h(struct icmphdr* hdr,int *msg_count)
 {
    hdr->type = ICMP_ECHO;
    hdr->un.echo.id = 1; 
    hdr->un.echo.sequence = (*msg_count)++; 
 }

 void fill_data(unsigned char * data)
 {
  memset(data, 'J', PING_PKT_S-sizeof(struct icmphdr));
 }

 void fill_eth(struct ethhdr* eth){
 eth->h_source[0] = 0x78;
 eth->h_source[1] = 0xe7;
 eth->h_source[2] = 0xd1;
 eth->h_source[3] = 0xe2;
 eth->h_source[4] = 0xc3;
 eth->h_source[5] = 0x48;
 eth->h_dest[0] = 0xc0;
 eth->h_dest[1] = 0x42;
 eth->h_dest[2] = 0xd0;
 eth->h_dest[3] = 0x6e;
 eth->h_dest[4] = 0xe1;
 eth->h_dest[5] = 0xd9;
 eth->h_proto = htons(ETH_P_IP);
}

int recv_ping(int ping_sockfd)
{ 
 int addr_len,msg_received_count=0,on =1; 
 struct sockaddr_ll r_addr; 
 /*struct timespec time_start, time_end, tfs, tfe; 
 long double rtt_msec=0, total_msec=0; 
 struct timeval tv_out;*/
char* buffer = (char*) malloc (65536);

 /*Timer Settings*/
 //tv_out.tv_sec = RECV_TIMEOUT; 
 //tv_out.tv_usec = 0; 
 //clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tfs);

 addr_len=sizeof(r_addr);
memset(buffer,0,65536);

 if ( recvfrom(ping_sockfd, buffer, 65536, 0, 
                (struct sockaddr*)&r_addr, &addr_len) <= 0 ) { 
        printf("\nPacket receive failed!\n"); 
 } 

 else{ 
    /*clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time_end); 

    double timeElapsed = ((double)(time_end.tv_nsec - 
                    time_start.tv_nsec))/1000000.0; 
    rtt_msec = (time_end.tv_sec - time_start.tv_sec) * 1000.0 + timeElapsed; 

    msg_received_count++;*/

    struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr*) (buffer);
    unsigned short iphdrlen;
    struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr*)(buffer + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
    if((unsigned int)ip->protocol==1){
        printf("\n Ethernet Header \n");
        printf("\t|Source Address : %.2X - %.2X - %.2X - %.2X - %.2X - %.2X",eth->h_source[0],eth->h_source[1],eth->h_source[2],eth->h_source[3],eth->h_source[4],eth->h_source[5]);
        printf("\t|Destination Address : %.2X - %.2X - %.2X - %.2X - %.2X - %.2X",eth->h_dest[0],eth->h_dest[1],eth->h_dest[2],eth->h_dest[3],eth->h_dest[4],eth->h_dest[5]);


        printf("\n Internet header \n");
        printf("\t|-Version : %d\n",(unsigned int)ip->version);
        printf("\t|-Internet Header Length : %d DWORDS or %d Bytes\n",(unsigned int)ip->ihl,((unsigned int)(ip->ihl))*4);
        printf("\t|-Type Of Service : %d\n",(unsigned int)ip->tos);
        printf("\t|-Total Length : %d Bytes\n",ntohs(ip->tot_len));
        printf("\t|-Identification : %d\n",ntohs(ip->id));
        printf("\t|-Time To Live : %d\n",(unsigned int)ip->ttl);
        printf("\t|-Protocol : %d\n",(unsigned int)ip->protocol);
        printf("\t|-Header Checksum : %d\n",ntohs(ip->check));
        printf("\t|-Source IP : %d\n", ip->saddr);
        printf("\t|-Destination IP : %d\n",ip->daddr);
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}    
} 



void send_ping(ping_ctx* ctx,int r_sock)
{ 
int  msg_count=0, i, addr_len, pkt_sent=1, 
    msg_received_count=0,on =1; 
struct sockaddr_ll remote_addr; 
struct ip *ip = NULL;
struct icmphdr* icmph = NULL;
unsigned  char* data = NULL;
struct ethhdr* eth = NULL;
struct sockaddr_ll r_addr; 
struct timespec time_start, time_end, tfs, tfe; 
long double rtt_msec=0, total_msec=0; 
struct timeval tv_out;

/*Set params*/ 
char *to = ctx->dstIP;
char *from = ctx->srcIP;
int   ping_sockfd = ctx->r_sock;
int ttl = ctx->ttl;
int tos =ctx->tos;

/*Timer Settings*/
tv_out.tv_sec = RECV_TIMEOUT; 
tv_out.tv_usec = 0; 
//clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tfs); 

//GET INTERFACE INDEX FOR INTERFACE enp0s3
/*struct ifreq ifr;
size_t if_name_len = strlen(if_name);
if(if_name_len<sizeof(ifr.ifr_name)){
     memcpy(ifr.ifr_name,if_name,if_name_len);
     ifr.ifr_name[if_name_len]=0;
}
else{
     die("Interface name is too long");
}
memset(&ifr,0,sizeof(ifr));
strncpy(ifr.ifr_name,enp0s3,IFNAMSIZ-1);
int fd = socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
if(fd==-1)
     printf("Error opening socket");
if(ioctl(fd,SIOCGIFINDEX,&ifr)==-1){
     printf("Error getting index name");
}*/
//int ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
int ifindex = if_nametoindex("enp2s0f0");
printf("The interface number is : %d \n",ifindex);

remote_addr.sll_ifindex = ifindex;
remote_addr.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN;
remote_addr.sll_addr[0] = 0xc0;
remote_addr.sll_addr[1] = 0x42;
remote_addr.sll_addr[2] = 0xd0;
remote_addr.sll_addr[3] = 0x6e;
remote_addr.sll_addr[4] = 0xe1;
remote_addr.sll_addr[5] = 0xd9;

while(pingloop) 
{ 
    pkt_sent=1; 
    memset(&g_pckt, 0, sizeof(g_pckt));

    /*ETHERNET Header*/
    eth = (struct ethhdr *)&g_pckt;
    fill_eth(eth);

    /*IP Header*/        
    ip = (struct ip *)(eth + 1); 
    fill_ip_h(ip, ctx);

    /*ICMP Header*/
    icmph = (struct icmphdr*)(ip + 1);
    fill_icmp_h(icmph, &msg_count); 

    /*Data*/
    data = (unsigned char *)(icmph + 1);
    fill_data(data);

    /*ICMP Checksum*/
    icmph->checksum = checksum(icmph, PING_PKT_S);

    usleep(PING_SLEEP_RATE); 

    /*TX*/ 
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time_start); 
    if ( sendto(ping_sockfd, &g_pckt, sizeof(g_pckt), 0, 
                (struct sockaddr*) &remote_addr, 
                sizeof(remote_addr)) <= 0) 
    { 
        printf("\nPacket Sending Failed!\n"); 
        pkt_sent=0; 
    } 

    /*RX*/ 
    /*addr_len=sizeof(r_addr); 

    if ( recvfrom(ping_sockfd, icmph, PING_PKT_S, 0, 
                (struct sockaddr*)&r_addr, &addr_len) <= 0 
            && msg_count>1) 
    { 
        printf("\nPacket receive failed!\n"); 
    } */

    else
    { 
        /*clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time_end); 

        double timeElapsed = ((double)(time_end.tv_nsec - 
                    time_start.tv_nsec))/1000000.0; 
        rtt_msec = (time_end.tv_sec- 
                time_start.tv_sec) * 1000.0 
            + timeElapsed;*/ 

        // if packet was not sent, don't receive 
        if(pkt_sent) 
        { 
            msg_count++;
            if(recv_ping(r_sock)){
                msg_received_count++;
            }

            //printf("Total Messages received : %d\n", msg_received_count ); 
            /*if(!(g_pckt.hdr.type ==69 && g_pckt.hdr.code==0)) 
            { 
                printf("Error..Packet received with ICMP" 
                        "type %d code %d\n", 
                        g_pckt.hdr.type, g_pckt.hdr.code); 
            } 
            else
            { 
                printf("%d bytes Received reply from %s: icmp_seq=:%d ttl=%d time=%Lf ms\n",PING_PKT_S, ctx->dstIP, msg_count, ctx->ttl, rtt_msec); 
                msg_received_count++;
            } */
        } 
    }    
} 
/*clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tfe); 
double timeElapsed = ((double)(tfe.tv_nsec - 
            tfs.tv_nsec))/1000000.0; 

total_msec = (tfe.tv_sec-tfs.tv_sec)*1000.0+ 
    timeElapsed ;*/

printf("\n%d packets sent, %d packets received\n\n", 
        msg_count, msg_received_count); 
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
ping_ctx ctx = {0};

if(argc!=3) 
{ 
    printf("sudo ./myping 10.117.157.6 10.39.51.117\n"); 
    return 0; 
} 

signal(SIGINT, intHandler); 
ctx.r_sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW); 
int r_sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP)); 
if(r_sock <0) 
{ 
    printf("\nSocket file descriptor not received\n"); 
    return 0; 
} 
if(ctx.r_sock <0) 
{ 
    printf("%d",ctx.r_sock);
    printf("\nSocket file descriptor not received\n"); 
    return 0; 
} 

ctx.tos = 0;
ctx.ttl = 64;
strncpy(ctx.dstIP, argv[1],strlen(argv[1]));
strncpy(ctx.srcIP, argv[2],strlen(argv[2]));

send_ping(&ctx,r_sock); 

return 0; 
}
```

Also the sendto api as called is returning a value of 0 indicating only 0 bytes have been sent which shouldn't be the ideal case as it is supposed to return the number of bytes sent which should be equal to the packet size.

I know the code posted is long but I was unsure which part is causing the error. So I'd to post the whole code. Any quick help will be appreciated.

The tcpdump capture for the Linux sender is shown below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSwkB.png)

Comment: Just for information : My Linux machine address : MAC : 78:E7:D1:E2:C3:48 IP : 10.39.51.117 My Gateway MAC : C0:42:D0:6E:E1:D9 My windows IP : 10.117.159.251.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out. Apparently AF_PACKET always assumes that the packet will be completely filled. By completely I MEAN COMPLETELY. And I was trying to leave out the IPv4 checksum for the kernel to fill in which though was being successful for AF_INET but is not the case for AF_PACKET. So it was compulsory for AF_PACKET to fill the checksum and doing so everything got fine.